# open mp applied to while loop

Tags: c++, openmp

I have got the following recursive code which I am trying to do in parallel using c++ open mp library. At the moment I have just added the clause #pragma omp parallel (because I can't use tasks due to visual studio supporting only omp 2.0) before the loop but it actually slows down the speed. What am I doing wrong?

Ok. Following your advice about using omp sections I have rewritten my code. So now it looks like below. However, it is still slower than the sequential version..

```
  long long p (long long n, long long mmm)
  {
        long long c = 0;        
        long exponent = 0;
        double ex;
        long counter = 1;
        long long ttt = 0;
        long long ttt1 = 0;

        long long b = 0;
        long long a = 0;
        long long h = 0;


        while (counter > 0)
        {
            ex = pow(-1, counter - 1);
            exponent = (long) ex;

            ttt = (n - ( (counter * ( (3 * counter) - 1)) / 2));
            ttt1 = (n - ( (counter * ( (3 * counter) + 1)) / 2));
            #pragma omp parallel sections
            {
                #pragma omp section
                {                       
                    if (ttt == 0 || ttt == 1)
                        {
                            a = exponent * 1;
                            c = c + a;
                        }
                    else if (ttt>0)
                    {                       
                         a = exponent * p((n - ( (counter * ( (3 * counter) - 1)) / 2)), mmm);
                             c = c + a;
                    }
                }


                #pragma omp section
                {
                        //If n == 1 or 0 return 1 as per convention else do the calculation
                        if (ttt1 == 0 || ttt1 == 1)
                        {
                                b = exponent * 1;
                                c = c + b;
                        }
                        else if (ttt1 > 0)
                        {

                            b = exponent * p( (n - ( (counter * ( (3 * counter) + 1)) / 2)), mmm);
                            c = c + b;
                        }
                    }
           }    

            if (ttt < 0 && ttt1 < 0)
                break;

            ++counter;

        }
```

Comment: i might be blind but isnt this an infinite loop you are trying to parallelize? (i mean the only end cirterion is an break inside a condition, and thus might be hard for openmp to optimize - you would need to refractor)

Comment: it is a recursive algorithm. it stops when ttt and ttt1 < 0

Comment: I see you've just deleted the code, which is unhelpful. Is this an algorithm that can actually be parallelised at all?

Comment: Yes. The algorithm could be parallelised. I did it with tbb but can't use the directive task with open mp so that's why I am trying to find some other alternative..

Comment: The code has data-races on `c`

Comment: The sequential code performs about 80% faster than the open mp. I have revised my code so that now a and b are computed in parallel but it is still slower..

Comment: If you are specifically targetting visual studio, look up the Concurrency Runtime and `ppl.h`. It has a fair bit in common with tbb, and does allow task cancellation. Available in VS2010 onwards, even in the Express versions.

Comment: @user3017335 `ttt<0` exactly this condition will be achieven in some iteration. and every iteration explicitly depends on data from previous. how should openmp parallelize this loop as no iteration can be run parallely. you need to either refractor the code and use other techniques or change the implimentation

Comment: Oh well. As I said I wanted to use openMP task clause but they are available with omp 3.0 and visual studio supports only OMP 2.0. So what other possibilities I have got?

Answer (score 3):

The `#pragma omp parallel` defines a portion of code that will run in parallel. That means that you will have several parallel runs of the entire `while` loop, not parallel runs of the iterations of a single loop.

That means that there is an substantial overhead by OpenMP to manage concurrent read/write access to the variables, hence a larger total runtime.

If you intend to compute `a` and `b` in parallel you should probably mark the whole `if ... else if ... else` them as `omp section` assuming they are completely independent computations.

Automatic parallelization of loops can be done only with `for` loops with `#pragma omp parallel for`.

Comment: I have tried doing it with section but since I have got if..else if..else break, it tells me error C3010: 'break' : jump out of OpenMP structured block not allowed, due to the break condition